# Flutter changes the time received from my backend

Tags: mysql, node.js, date, flutter

When I send the date from my backend it has a format, but when I get it in flutter the format and time change.

I am using flutter as frontend and nodeJS as backend and MYSQL as DB.
In my backend I have the following code

```
    var req_date = moment (Date.now ()). tz ('America / Mexico_City'). format ('YYYY-MM-DD HH: mm: ss');
```

then I save it to my MSQL db as a timestamp, and in my DB it looks like this

```
2020-08-22 03:02:53
```

So, I make a request to my api from flutter, then receive it and send a request to my database which returns the following result

```
Sat, August 22, 2020 03:02:53 GMT-0500 (GMT-05: 00)
```

Then I send it as JSON and receive it in flutter.

But when I do a print on flutter. My flutter console shows me the following

```
Requested_date: 2020-08-22T08: 02: 53.000Z
```

The problem is with the time which in my backend is 3:02 but when I receive it in flutter it is 8:02.
I think it is something related to UTC timezone, but I don't know how to solve it because I want to get the same time as the backend.

Comment: It is the same time, just in different timezones. 03:02 Mexico City *is* 08:02 Zulu/UTC (note the Z suffix printed by Dart). Dart only natively handles time in either local timezone (as defined by the mobile device or browser) or UTC - and allows you to convert easily between the two. There's a package called `timezone` that lets you convert times to arbitrary timezones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve my problem.

I solved it as follows:
I first took the bd request and modified it to ISO 8601 format and transformed it to a string before sending it to flutter.
Then when I received it on Flutter, I was able to capture the response and display it.

**1. Conversion to ISO 8601.**

I first made a request to my database and I converted the result to ISO 860.

```
var reqDateIsoString = new Date(bdRequest[0][i].date).toISOString();
```

**2. Give a local format**

I didn't use the toLocale method because I don't wanted to change my date relative to my server because my goal was to display a history so I had to handle it as a constant. So I used the "moment" library for nodeJS.

```
npm install moment
var moment = require('moment');
var reqDateWithFormat = moment(reqDateIsoString).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
```

**3. Conversion to string.**

As a last step, I converted the data to a string to prevent Flutter changed the time to UTC.

```
var reqDateString = String (reqDateWithFormat);
```

Then I sent it to Flutter and was able to display the date as a string as I needed.

Thanks to [Richard Heap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9597706/richard-heap)